# DialogFlowCX console (NOT API) "Invalid update mask" in saving routes

Tags: dialogflow-cx

Impossible for me to save any route in the Start flow on DialogFlow CX console. I always get the same message: "invalid update mask.".

Tried to re-open browser, switch browser, clear cache and cookies, go on another device but same issue.

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's an on-going bug regarding the Invalid update mask which started yesterday. You may check this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/269510535) for updates.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Just saw it. Thanks.